# Lua code, square in game

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a problem, the square and the circle you can see in the picture.

Do not know how to delete this, can anyone help me for do not show it?

The example of code is this:

```
supermanSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("superman.png", 100, 34)
supermanSprites = sprite.newSpriteSet(supermanSpriteSheet, 1, 4)
sprite.add(supermanSprites, "supermanes", 1, 4, 1000, 0)
superman = sprite.newSprite(supermanSprites)
superman.x = 0
superman.y = 100
superman:prepare("supermanes")
superman:play()
superman.collided = false
fisica.addBody(superman, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2})
screenGroup:insert(superman)
supermanIntro = transition.to(superman,{time=1000, x=100, onComplete=supermanReady})
```

The image of game:

[image: img]

Answer (score 4):

You may have enabled  `physics rendering mode/DrawMode` as `hybrid` in your game. So, comment the following line:

```
physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid" )
```

or replace it with the following line:

```
physics.setDrawMode( "normal" )
```

For more details, visit: [physics.setDrawMode](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html)

Keep Coding..................... :)